# interpolate between dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation, pyspark

I have two python data frames which contain two columns with latitudes and longitudes and one column with a variable value ( meteorological data). They look like this: 
df1: ( LAT_GIN is my dataframe index).

```
LAT_GIN        W_C    LON_GIN

64.601875 -0.046970  23.601875
64.603096 -0.045264  23.603096
64.604317 -0.069111  23.604317
64.605530 -0.105219  23.605530
64.606750 -0.103395  23.606750
64.607971 -0.127782  23.607971
64.609192 -0.163193  23.609192
64.610420 -0.154366  23.610420
64.611641 -0.187829  23.611641
64.612862 -0.196406  23.612862
```

and df2 (XLAT is also the Dataframe index)

```
XLAT         XLONG       XLAT    W_2500    W_3050                                               
64.703163 -23.371796  64.703163 -0.224206 -0.044160
64.806923 -23.381836  64.806923  0.747201  0.634281
64.898018 -23.187042  64.898018 -2.801987 -2.411570
64.896782 -23.291870  64.896782 -3.735538 -3.538459
64.914314 -23.314056  64.914314 -2.808161 -1.526975
65.069244 -23.179199  65.069244  2.931657  3.399997
65.189682 -23.378845  65.189682  0.146263  0.065752
65.220207 -23.360535  65.220207  1.149238  1.235280
65.225952 -23.238251  65.225952  1.949269  2.052593
65.235298 -23.276123  65.235298  0.574646  0.776463
```

Df2 has much more points ( is a 600x600 lat lon grid with values of W_2500    W_3050 at every grid point). I would like to inteprolate the Df2 W_2500 values defined on the XLAT XLONG grid to the coarser df1 Lat and lon values ( LAT_GIN, LON_GIN).
So basically I want to get the values of my W_2500 on the values of lat and lon in df1. 
How can I do that ?